# Source js file of event listener

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

Is there a way I could identify the source file of a specific event?

My events are being removed, because the usage of document.open usage in the code. This is something can't change. I am trying to re-use my events, but because of another limitation I have, I need to know which events are coming from different JS files.

```
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListenerBase = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener = function(type,listener,params)
{

    var isFromSourceX = "nameoffile.js"
    var worker_events = ['DOMContentLoaded',
     'beforeunload', "blue","devicemotion","deviceorientation",
     "error","focus","load","message","orientationchange",
     "resize","scroll","storage","click"];
    var _this=this;
    var _isEventExists = window._stackedListeners.filter(function(item){ return item.type==type && item.target==_this; })[0]===undefined?false:true;
    var isHtmlElement = this instanceof HTMLElement;
    if (worker_events.indexOf(type)>-1 && !_isEventExists && isFromSourceX) {
        window._stackedListeners.push({
            target: _this,
            type: type,
            listener: listener,
            params: params
        });
        this.addEventListenerBase(type, listener, params);
    }
};
})(self);
```

Eventually, I'll be pushing all needed events to an array to later attach them on the web page. But the problem as mentioned, is that I need to identify the source (to exclude external events) in the webpage.

p.s: I did not chose to work with document.open :)

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you tend to use Chrome Dev Tools you will be able to see all the events associated with the specific type if you open the Source tab. On the right pane in Event listener breakpoints you could check the event category that you are interested in. By executing specific ones you will be able to see the source file.

It does not give you all the event listeners out of the box but it could be helpful if you are trying to diagnose your issue. You could also find event listeners on a dom node by inspecting it. On the right pane there should be a list of event listeners for it.

Hope I gave you some glimpse.

Comment: using the debugger, I am able to see the "FunctionLocation" param, which I cannot find during runtime. This could solve the issue if it was available during runtime and not through developer tools